# Django on Heroku - browser emulator with javascript plugin

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm writing a project in **Django** which is to run on **Heroku** PaaS. Within my code base, I would like to be able to perform some tests on links, ex.: **open them in a browser**.

What's most important to me is that I need to execute the **javascript**.

Are there any emulators of browser in Python which supports javascript emulation (I know mechanize doesn't, I tried splinter and spynner - but I have some difficulties in using them on heroku, to use splinter I'd need PyQt, to use spynner I'd need firefox - and I don't know how to install them - I guess it is not possible, is it?).

Of course I'm not fixed on Python. I mean, I've thought about another possibility - to write a Perl script (I have already written a script which does what I want it to do) and execute it from Python (I know how to do that) - but I don't know if it's possible to run Perl script from a Python code on Heroku.

Can anybody help me please?

Regards,
Natalia

Comment: Most headless browser engines use webkit, via PyQT. The alternatives are all using *some* browser engine and thus all need installing (compiling). You'll need to figure that part out, whatever language you'll script it in.

Comment: I think in this case a VPS is necessary or employign services of another PaaS just for the testing part such as IronWorker where the whole thing can be tested using PhantomJS?

Comment: Testing execution of Javascript should also be tested with Javascript. Depending on your JS framework you use or add a test framework like Jasmine. Probably you don't even need a headless browser like PhantomJS.